# Is there a JavaFX 8 changelog?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Now that Java 8 has been released, is there a (reasonably comprehensive) changelog around for JavaFX 8, and if so where is it?

The only thing I've been able to find is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html) where FX is a subcategory, and it's clearly not a full list (I'm already aware of a few things that have changed or been fixed that aren't on there.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the [Java 8 what's new page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html) you linked a pretty good summary of new features in JavaFX 8.

For more detail on the JavaFX changes for Java 8, see the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Here is a collated feature list extracted from the issue tracker.

```
RT-15332    App Model   Allow application to catch exceptions thrown by FX application thread with an UncaughtExceptionHandler
RT-18024    Animation   Evaluate TODOs in code, either removing or filing issues as appropriate
RT-18400    Build       Support cross build for Linux embedded
RT-28089    Build       Write Script to auto-generate the new repository layout
RT-138      Control     Support component orientation in common UI controls
RT-10343    Control     CSS add support for CSS3 @font-face
RT-16201    Control     Creating an image icon only button should be able to specify the padding of the button via the api and not just through using CSS.
RT-16288    Control     Add a TextField.setFont method
RT-16395    Control     Support object oriented approach to styling UI components
RT-16472    Control     insets should be a real property on Region
RT-16689    Control     TextInputControl: css "-fx-columns" doesn't work
RT-17288    Control     Add a TreeTable
RT-19451    Control     TableView: Displaying hierarchical groups and data
RT-20906    Control     Support setting min/pref/max sizes via css
RT-21355    Control     Support user-defined pseudoclasses
RT-21709    Control     Consider making available the CSS Styleable* classes as public API
RT-23074    Control     Support bi-directional text in controls
RT-23075    Control     Support complex characters in controls
RT-27480    Control     Add DatePicker control
RT-27582    Control     New modern theme for JavaFX (Modena)
RT-15109    Core Libraries  ListChangeListener$Change.toString() is not implemented
RT-17053    Core Libraries  Reintroduce SortedList/FilteredList and TransformationList
RT-18804    Core Libraries  Add emptyObservableSet and emptyObservableMap in FXCollections
RT-19020    Core Libraries  Default conversion from ObservableObjectValue<Integer> to ObservableIntegerValue etc.
RT-19049    Core Libraries  Support standard Java Beans in SelectBinding
RT-19821    Core Libraries  Need private API to allow discovery of installed listeners on properties for testing
RT-20653    Core Libraries  Implement synchronized ObservableMap and synchronized ObservableSet
RT-20708    Core Libraries  Provide debugging and/or error condition feedback mechanism in high-level binding routines
RT-21487    Core Libraries  Add isEmpty() and length() methods to StringExpression
RT-23600    Core Libraries  ObservableListBase
RT-25759    Core Libraries  ObjectExpression does not have asString() method
RT-25996    Core Libraries  "Primitive"Property to ObjectProperty<Primitive>
RT-27633    Core Libraries  Add missing FXCollections methods for ObservableSet
RT-30831    Core Libraries  Unsorted mode in the SortedList
RT-17714    FXML        Support collection events in FXML
RT-25559    FXML        In FXML, Allow event handlers to come from the namespace
RT-11561    Glass       Some cursor images are incorrect on Windows, Linux and Mac
RT-20020    Glass       Windows: support Aero Glass effects for top-level windows
RT-9372     Graphics    Add Back-face Culling support to JavaFX
RT-9411     Graphics    Define internal API for styled text
RT-17383    Graphics    Printing
RT-17392    Graphics    Multi-line, multi-style, rich text support
RT-17401    Graphics    3D geometry support
RT-17411    Graphics    Complex text with BiDi support
RT-17663    Graphics    Define javafx printing APIs
RT-18149    Graphics    Integrate ICU library for opentype layout
RT-19040    Graphics    Add native font rasterization for Mac
RT-21683    Graphics    Allow to change line-to-line spacing
RT-24008    Graphics    3D attributes
RT-24009    Graphics    Support for Hi-DPI displays
RT-24012    Graphics    Text performance of the hardware pipeline must be equal or better than the software pipeline
RT-24013    Graphics    Multi-Core scalability
RT-24644    Graphics    Support Mesh and Predefined 3D Shapes
RT-24651    Graphics    Need clean semantic for 2D/3D scenes mixing
RT-24654    Graphics    Need to include lighting and material support for 3D primitives rendering
RT-24655    Graphics    Need to support movable Camera
RT-24712    Graphics    Support ATI/AMD GPU on the Linux platform
RT-25606    Graphics    Port 3D features from demo/experimental repository to FX 8 3D sandbox
RT-26377    Graphics    Implement SubScene
RT-24595    Localization    L10N: Java FX must be localized in all the different languages as supported by the JRE
RT-28817    Media       Add explicit dispose() method to MediaPlayer
RT-24014    Other       FX needs to support a subset of the JRE supported systems
RT-24648    Other       Define supported Linux configurations
RT-3290     Scenegraph  need utility methods for converting to/from screen coordinates
RT-3518     Scenegraph  multiline multistyle text node
RT-9383     Scenegraph  Add proper constructors & factory methods to event classes, remove impl
RT-12723    Scenegraph  Ability to Render a Node in an another Node (NodeView)
RT-14730    Scenegraph  Drag and drop needs support for drag view
RT-16111    Scenegraph  FileChooser: Need to be able to specify initial file name in save dialog
RT-17645    Scenegraph  Make Image class support exceptions for both asynchronous and synchronous loading
RT-17942    Scenegraph  Provide Affine class with matrix manipulation methods (multiply, premultipy, negate, etc.)
RT-19834    Scenegraph  The solid white background created in a Stage should be created - if needed - in the Scenegraph
RT-24506    Scenegraph  Public API for Region backgrounds and borders
RT-29848    Scenegraph  Add a static GridPane.setFillWidth(Node, boolean) method
RT-12100    Swing       Swing components inside JavaFX
RT-27887    Swing       introduce a node to embed Swing into JavaFX
RT-9782     WebView     Workers API is incomplete
RT-14947    WebView     websockets not working in WebEngine
RT-17666    WebView     Webview and HTMLEditor should support printing their content
RT-21499    WebView     Add WebView.scale property
RT-22153    WebView     Allow setting custom user-agent
RT-22913    WebView     Implement and enable accelerated compositing to improve WebView rendering performance
RT-25644    WebView     Implement WebSocket traffic tunneling through HTTP(S) proxies that require authentication
RT-28499    WebView     WebView doesnot support HTML5 <input type=file multiple
RT-29584    WebView     Implement window.localStorage
RT-29834    WebView     Move JSObject into javafx-ui-common
RT-30236    WebView     Open WebView sources
```

When searching the issue tracker, use Lombard as the search version to find issues related to the initial Java 8 release.

- Over [three thousand issues were fixed](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=project%20=%20RT%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Fixed%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20Lombard) as part of the Lombard release.
- Another one and a half thousand issues were closed as incomplete, duplicate, etc.
- [2350 bugs](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=project%20=%20RT%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Bug%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Fixed%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20Lombard) were fixed.  Many of these bug reports did not relate to production code, but were bugs in new features which were caught by QA and fixed prior to release.
- [408 tweaks](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=project%20=%20RT%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Tweak%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Fixed%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20Lombard) were made.  These are minor feature changes and small API additions.
- [87 features](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=project%20=%20RT%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Feature%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Fixed%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20Lombard%20AND%20component%20!=%20Tests%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20ASC) were implemented.

JavaFX development continues and [over 300 additional issues](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=project%20=%20RT%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Fixed%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%208u20%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC) have been resolved for distribution in a future Java 8u20 release.

Another major change for [JavaFX 8](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main) compared to earlier versions, is that the project is now completely open source.

Answer (score 0):

I you are interested in all new classes and methods you can search for this annotation: @since JavaFX 8.0