# Java FX for SE7 or SE8

Tags: java, javafx

I will be making a Java application using Java FX. I want to use SE8, but I'm concerned that Java FX isn't as usable in SE8 as SE7; has anyone used Java FX in SE8 and can confirm that it isn't buggy or difficult to use? Thanks, I don't want to have to switch platforms in the middle if it gets messy!

Comment: First off, please show the documentation that you have that shows that Java FX is buggy in SE8.

Comment: I don't, it's just that it's new--that's what I'm asking

Comment: This might help: http://java.dzone.com/articles/whats-new-java-8-part-i-javafx

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'd like to add that my group ended up writing about 5k lines of code in JavaFX. The scene graph's tree structure and reactive programming proved to be awesome. Highly recommend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review the answer to: [Is there a JavaFX 8 changelog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508186/is-there-a-javafx-8-changelog)

Then decide for yourself if you would rather use Java 7 or Java 8, given that:

1. Many bugs in the JavaFX implementation in Java 7 were fixed in Java 8.
2. Many features were added to JavaFX in Java 8 which are not present in Java 7.
3. Numerous [architectural performance improvements](http://fxexperience.com/2012/09/preliminary-performance-numbers-in-javafx-8/) were implemented for Java 8.
4. The currently scheduled date for [end of public updates](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) for Java 7 is April, 2015.
5. The JavaFX project developers rarely backport bug fixes from the Java 8 branch to earlier branches.

Is JavaFX in Java 8 bug free? => No.

The Java 8u20 update release will include many (mostly minor) bug fixes for JavaFX.

Future Java 7 update releases will not include the majority of these bug fixes.

Does JavaFX in Java 8 have fewer bugs than JavaFX in Java 7? => Certainly.

The major issue with JavaFX development on Java 8 at the moment is the [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) tool for Java 8 is only in early access release.  However, it will have a production release quite soon and the latest early access release builds for SceneBuilder are quite usable.