# Is it possible to use the latest version of JavaFX with JDK 7?

Tags: javafx, java-7

Is the latest version of `JavaFX` that is included in `JDK 8` compatible with `Java 7`? Oracle says [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp) that the latest version is included in JDK but I wonder if it is included in the latest update of `JDK 7` and whether or not it is the same version as in the `JDK 8`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The latest version of JavaFX 8 is incompatible with Java 7 !**

You can use javafx 2.x with any version of Java 7. But in order to use JavaFX 8, you need Java 8 !

**Update** (as per user requirement)

There are loads and loads of bug fixes from javafx2 to javafx8. There are many noticeable changes as well. Few of them are as follows :

- **New Look** - Javafx8 comes with a new UI, a fresh look called Modena. For more details, visit [this](http://fxexperience.com/2013/03/modena-theme-update/)
- **Print API** - After Java Printer API, used in awt, for the very first time a new Printing support has be added to JavaFX
- **Swing Node** - Swing node will allow you to embed swing components inside a javafx scene. Support for the opposite, is already possible via JFXPanel.
- **Improved 3D support** - Camera, 3Dprimitives, Light, 3DAttributes are few things that you can look in JavaFX8 3D support. There are many more.
- **New UI Controls** - DatePicker and the TreeTableView controls has been added
- **Support for Hi-DPI displays has been added in this release.**

The whole list of changes can be found *What's new in JDK 8*, under the [JavaFX section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html)

Comment: So,  javafx 2.x is different than  javafx 8?

Comment: I want to upvote and downvote this at the same time. It's because I was searching for the information about JDK-FX compatibility (in sense of versions), and the first sentence give me some clue.
However, the main part of the answer consist of mentioning differences between JavaFX 2 and 8, and that is not what was asked (at least in the question), so it does not feel good. Rather than than, I would like to see (and even expected I think) a reference to this information or some table showing which JavaFX versions we can use with which JDKs.

Comment: If you check before starting the second part, I wrote "Update (as per user requirement)", which indicates that it was written as an update to answer the question asked by the OP in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the latest version of JavaFX with JDK 7

There is a OpenJFX 8 backport to Java SE 7. I don't know its current state. I think its maintained by the OpenJFX on Android/ iOS community.

https://bitbucket.org/narya/jfx78/wiki/Home

But I recommend to use Java SE 8 if you want to use JavaFX 8.

> Oracle says here that the latest version is included in JDK but I
>   wonder if it is included in the latest update of JDK 7 and whether or
>   not it is the same version as in the JDK 8?

Oracle's Java SE 7 contains JavaFX 2.x and Oracle's Java SE 8 contains JavaFX 8.
They are not the same.

Comment: So, "javafx 2.x" is different than "javafx 8"?

Comment: Yes, they are different.

Comment: Do you know exactly what the differences are?

Comment: Have a look at the "What's New in JDK 8" page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html
Additionally, there are probably implementation changes (clean-ups, usage of Java SE 8 language features, ...).

Comment: A [JavaFX 8 changelog summary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508186/is-there-a-javafx-8-changelog) is on StackOverflow.

Comment: The bitbucket link is dead.